# Error 168: The store provider factory type 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory' does not implement the IServiceProvider interface

Tags: visual-studio-2010, edmx

I have the following error :
Error 168: The store provider factory type 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory' does not implement the IServiceProvider interface. Use a store provider that implements this interface.

The problem is happening on the file DiscoModel.edmx :

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <edmx:Edmx Version="2.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/10/edmx">
       <!-- EF Runtime content -->
      <edmx:Runtime>
        <!-- SSDL content -->
       <edmx:StorageModels>
          <Schema Namespace="DiscoModel.Store" Alias="Self" Provider="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" ProviderManifestToken="11.2" xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl">`

on the following line :

```
<Schema Namespace="DiscoModel.Store" Alias="Self" Provider="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" ProviderManifestToken="11.2" xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl">
```

I changed ProviderManifestToken="11.1" to ProviderManifestToken="11.2", I verified that we were using .Net Framework 4, I installed ODP .net, be sure that the Entity Model Framework was installed, verified that we point on the right Oracle.dataaccess.client.dll (11.2.0.3),

but I still got this error ? Why ? What I can do ?

Thanks for your answers,

Nicolas Maujean

Comment: Someone of my team has the solution working on his computer. I copied his solution on my computer but get the same error